# construction of open subsets in classifying space $BG$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group and we
construct the classifying space $BG$ as quotient
of $EG$ where the latter one is considered in
this discussion to be constructed in natural way as $\Delta$-complex by
method from [Hatcher's AT book](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) on page 89. That means all $n$-simplices of $EG$
are the ordered $(n + 1)$ tuples $[g_0, ..., g_n]$
of elements of $G$ glued together along
faces $[g_0, ..., \hat{g_i},..., g_n]$ in canonical
way. For concrete geometrical realization of such formally defined
$n$-simplex $[g_0, ..., g_n]$ we identify
$g_0,..., g_n$ with $(n+1)$ real points
in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ which
are affinely independent, which means
$g_1-g_0,... g_n-g_0$ are linearly independent.
Then we can write $[g_0, ..., g_n]$ as

$$ \{ \theta_0 g_0 + ... \theta_n g_n \ \vert \
\sum_{i=0}^n \theta_i=1 \text{ and } \theta_i \ge 0\}  $$
and endow it naturally with Euklidian topology.
The group $G$ acts on $EG$ by left multiplication,
an element $g \in G$ takes the
simplex $[g_0, ..., g_n]$
linearly onto the simplex $[gg_0, ..., gg_n]$ and by definition
$BG= EG/G$.

My goal is to understand locally the topology
of $BG$ better. *Is there a standard method known
to construct open subsets in $BG$?*
Note that since $BG$ inherits a $\Delta$-complex
structure from $EG$, an subset $O \subset BG$
is open iff the intersection of $U$ with any
simplex of $BG$ is open with respect to the induced standard
Euklidian topology.

It seems naturally for me instead to work with complicated
$BG$ to try to construct open
subsets in $EG$, but assure
that these are $G$-invariant with respect
the described action.
Is there a most "natural, not too exotic" way (ways?) known to construct
such open $G$-invariant subsets $O \in EG$. Moreover can these
be arranged to form a cover of $EG$ and therefore
that their images under $EG \to BG$ to form a cover
of $BG$.

Contain such constructions also some geometric intuition
or are these done pure axiomatically?

Comment: Do you have in mind $G$ to be a Lie group or a discrete one?

Comment: One important thing to know is that there are several non-homeomorphic constructions of $BG$. Indeed $BG$ is usually only well-defined as a *(pointed) homotopy type*. This doesn't mean that the question you're asking cannot be interesting, but it is in some sense "strange", since it is about a specific model.

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio: an abstract one, so with a discrete topology

Comment: @DenisNardin: I tried to choose a model that seems to carry the most elementary geometric structure. And simpler then that one of a $\Delta$-complex I don't know. But yes you are right that from the homotopy theoretical viewpoint such approach has not the potential to provide deep insights. My motivation is just to get some geometric intuition of $BG$ by considering a specific model which seems to me to be most approachable from naive-geometric viewpoint.